# Double indirection

Tags: c++, indirection

The problem is as follows.
I have a struct:

```
typedef unsigned int nat;

struct intervalo_t{
    nat fin;
    nat inicio;
};
```

I have done the following (where `inter` is a dynamic array of size `n` with elements of type `intervalo_t` that is loaded):

```
intervalo_t** aux=new intervalo_t*[n];
for (nat i=0; i<n; i++){
    aux[i]=inter[i];
}
```

What I need to do now is to show the content of `inter[i].fin`, but I only have access to `aux[i]`. If they were of a primitive type (say `int` for example) I would do something like `printf("%d", **aux)`, and that would be it. Is there a way of doing something like that but with the struct that's been defined above?

Comment: How about `aux[i]->fin`?

Comment: That worked, thanks

Comment: If I read the question carefully, I think you're saying you have `intervalo_t *inter` rather than `intervalo_t **inter`.  I don't think I lost any `*` when I edited the question.  If that were the case, the `aux[i] = inter[i];` assignment would be wrong.  So, presumably `inter` is an array of pointers to `intervalo_t` structures.  But either way, the problem would be resolved if you showed the declaration/definition of `inter` — a comment stating that its elements are properly initialized would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`inter[i]` is of type `intervalo_t*` so you can use `(*inter[i]).fin` or `inter[i]->fin`. Same goes for `aux[i]` which is also a `intervalo_t*`.